# ContextLoaderListener exception in tomcat startup

Tags: java, spring, maven, model-view-controller, tomcat9

I have this exception after installation on new system

> SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener
>   instance of class 
>       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>       Error creating bean with     'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource
>       [/server/configuration/DatabaseConfig.class]: 
>       Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
>       javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

With config:

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <javax.servlet-api.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet-api.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.9.2.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <hibernate.version>5.0.2.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mysql.version>6.0.6</mysql.version>
    <commons-dbcp2.version>2.1.1</commons-dbcp2.version>
    <jackson-databind.version>2.5.3</jackson-databind.version>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <firebase.version>6.6.0</firebase.version>
    <model-mapper>2.3.2</model-mapper>
</properties>
```

What is a problem?

Could somebody help? Previous was fine, but now it doesn't want work

Regards, Kirill

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably use Java > 8. In Java 9 JAXB was removed and now you need this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3-b02</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: HI, with this dependency it throw another exception:

Comment: SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processAnnotationsJar Unable to process Jar entry [module-info.class] from Jar [jar:file:/C:/Sandbox/Java/Subscriptionserver/target/com.ninja.subscription.server-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib/istack-commons-runtime-3.0.10.jar!/] for annotations

Comment: That’s another issue. It would be best if you found out which Java version you’re really running on. And if you want to upgrade to newest Java (currently 11 - at least for any serious work), then you need to upgrade all dependencies to latest versions. Btw. AFAIK Spring 4 is not compatible with Java 11. And obviously other libraries which you have in classpath have same issue. Or you can use Java 8.